# How do I get the full row of what is essentially a nested aggregate function in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table of events, and a table of participation in said events. I want to get the count of the people who participated at every fundraising event.

This is done successfully with:

```
SELECT Participate.eid, COUNT(Participate.pid) AS numpeople
FROM Participate
WHERE Participate.eid IN(
    SELECT Event.eid
    FROM Event
    WHERE Event.type = 'fundraising'
)
GROUP BY Participate.eid
```

This outputs a result of:

```
eid      numpeople
16           8
 6           7
 3          10
 5           6
```

What I want now is to get the maximum amount of people who attended a specific event.  First of all, I am required to not use any Views, and this is the only way I have been able to do it. I have also tried with derived tables but with no success.

I essentially want a result of:

```
eid     numpeople
 3         10
```

I tried doing this with derived tables, but it does not work because I'm forced to have a GROUP BY statement:

```
SELECT Temp1.eid, MAX(Temp1.numpeople) AS numpeople
FROM (
    SELECT Participate.eid, COUNT(Participate.pid) AS numpeople
    FROM Participate
    WHERE Participate.eid IN(
        SELECT Event.eid
        FROM Event
        WHERE Event.type = 'fundraising'
    )
    GROUP BY Participate.eid
) AS Temp1;
```

This is the closest thing I have gotten, but obviously, the 'eid' is not present in the row:

```
SELECT MAX(Temp1.numpeople) AS numpeople
FROM (
    SELECT Participate.eid, COUNT(Participate.pid) AS numpeople
    FROM Participate
    WHERE Participate.eid IN(
        SELECT Event.eid
        FROM Event
        WHERE Event.type = 'fundraising'
    )
    GROUP BY Participate.eid
) AS Temp1;
```

Which has output:

```
numpeople
   10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` and limit the result to one row:

```
SELECT p.eid, COUNT(p.pid) AS numpeople
FROM Participate p
WHERE p.eid IN (SELECT e.eid
                FROM Event e
                WHERE e.type = 'fundraising'
               )
GROUP BY p.eid
ORDER BY numpeople DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Not all databases support `FETCH FIRST`, so you might need to use `SELECT TOP` or `LIMIT`.